# Django ORM order by day from ISO time and score

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

HI in my database I have some data with created date and and some score associated with it.The created_date is of type DateTime. I am using django ORM.

The data is like

```
**col1   created_date                  score**
xxx    2019-05-28T10:07:57.000Z      8
yye    2019-05-27T10:07:57.000Z      9
abc    2019-05-28T09:07:57.000Z      10
```

I want my date to be sorted by day then score in descending order ie

```
abc    2019-05-28T09:07:57.000Z      10
xxx    2019-05-28T10:07:57.000Z      8
yye    2019-05-27T10:07:57.000Z      9
```

I am using

```
SomeModel.objects.values_list(col , score, created_date                                                                
).filter(somefilter tcategory=cat).order_by(
                        '-created_date__day',
                        '-score')
```

I am getting exception --

```
    raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a datetime_extract_sql() method')
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a datetime_extract_sql() method
```

Thanks

Comment: why dont you just try `-created_date` ?

Comment: I tried, the issue is on the same date The score is not descending order. In - created_date , it will also consider time also.

Comment: @RohitHaritash: but even if that was possible, it would still define some order on the time part, perhaps a random order, but I don't see why that is a problem here.

Comment: ok so, using -created_date I my order is like : 0.24
Tue, 28 May, 6:20 PM  followed by -- 0.31 Tue, 28 May, 6:16 PM. Now since both the scores are on 28th may, second entry should be first.

Comment: @RohitHaritash: but it looks very "strange" to order by date in descending order, and order by time in ascending order, since that means your ordering is a *non-C0* continuous.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's why i want to use only day filter of datetime type. Is it possible and correct approach. ? Thanks

Comment: @RohitHaritash: but if you order only by date, then it can still perfectly work out that time is ordered in descending order. After all, you make a less "crisp" ordering. In fact you made it even more worse since for one day it can order by time in ascending order, for another day in descending order, for another in a random and that all in the *same* queryset.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to make much sense to add a `__day` lookup here, you can just order in descending order by `created_by_date`:

```
SomeModel.objects.values_list(
    'col' , 'score', 'created_date'
).filter(
    somefilter tcategory=cat
).order_by('-created_date', '-score')
```

If you really want to order by the *date* of that day, you can use an annotation with [**`TruncDate`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate):

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

SomeModel.objects.values_list(
    'col' , 'score', 'created_date'
).annotate(
    create_day=TruncDate('created_date')
).filter(
    somefilter tcategory=cat
).order_by('-create_day', '-score')
```